# TYPO3 How to change the name of a TYPO3 website

Tags: typo3

I am trying to update the name of my website. Since I've only been working with TYPO3 for a short time, I don't know much about it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an **admin** backend user, go to **Amin Tools ➜ Settings** and click button "Configure options" in the box *Configure Installation-Wide Options*. Search for the keyword `sitename`.

In the section **System**, you'll find the input field that lets you change the global site name:

> `[SYS][sitename] = ...`

[image]

Save the new name by clicking the button "Write configuration" and reload the backend to see the change.

Comment: @blackplan Optionally you can edit `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` file and modify variable mentioned by@Michael. In both cases if changes don't work after refreshing while you're sure they are valid you'll just need to clear the cache using yellow lighting icon in the top menu of the BE.