# change website from old.mysite.com to new.mysite.com typo3 webserver

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

First: i am kind of a beginner in web administration. Please be patient ;)

I got a cloned VM from a server with a typo3 website on. i want to make it a test server to test updates and stuff before trying it on the real site.
I want the typo3 website to use staging.mywebsite.com instead of its normal url, but i am not sure where i need to change stuff in order for typo3 to work correctly.

what i did so far:

- renamed the folder under /var/www/old.mywebsite.com to staging.mywebsite.com
- change entries in /etc/hosts

But i am quite sure i need to change some config files too. Typo3 Version is 9.5

I found this:
[TYPO3 How to change the name of a TYPO3 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497721/typo3-how-to-change-the-name-of-a-typo3-website)

But i think thats not what i need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL for the website is defined in the site configuration, see [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/CreateNew.html).
You should modify the entry point as shown in the second image of the documentation (2) or just use the slash "/".
In your example you should use "https://staging.mywebsite.com/". Please keep in mind not forget the slash "/" after the domain.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that i just need to edit the config file under: <project-root>/typo3conf/sites/

Comment: Yes, you can edit the config file in "<project-root>/typo3conf/sites/" or use the module in TYPO3 backend that shows the file in an easier to understand way.